# remove/prevent chrome mobile dev tools context menu on long tap

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, mobile-chrome

I'm developing(debugging) a mobile app on chrome's mobile simulator, and I kinda irritated on chrome's context menu when you press and hold on the mobile. Is there a way to remove/prevent it from showing? Is there a feature on chrome to manually remove it?

I'd tried even using css user-select: none(prefix included), it is still showing it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable the context menu on long press when using device mode in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060472/how-to-disable-the-context-menu-on-long-press-when-using-device-mode-in-chrome)

Answer (score 3):

Listen for the `contextmenu` event and call its `preventDefault()` method:

```js
yourDomElement.addEventListener('contextmenu', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Since the event bubbles, you can put this anywhere up the DOM tree from the long-tapped element, even `document.body`. Just remember to take it off when you're finished debugging, otherwise users won't be able to open the right-click menu at any time.