# How to disable the context menu on long press when using device mode in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

How to disable the context menu on long press when using [device mode](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/) in Chrome ?

I mean this context menu:

[image]

I am asking this because I want to debug long press gestures for mobile devices and the context menu causes [my react app](http://commserver.asuscomm.com/src/main/index-fastopt.html) to behave in a strange way:

when I try to reorder the list then "strange things start to happen":  selected item starts to float all over the place (as can be seen from snapshot below). The Hello World is obscured by the selected item. Really strange.

[image]

Answer (score 27):

My workaround is entering this code into the JS console when testing long press actions in device mode:

```
window.oncontextmenu = function() { return false; }
```

Comment: It will actually lead to the context menu open 'never', really, so... might not be exactly what many people would be satisfied with. Is a decent workaround, however.

Answer (score 5):

I have developed a slightly more "advanced" workaround that will still (most of the time) show the contextmenu on right-click while preventing it from showing on a simulated long-tap:

```
window.oncontextmenu = function() {
    if (event.button != 2 && !(event.clientX == event.clientY == 1)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@marsk comment was right therefore based on previous answers I come up with another solution using [`PointerEvent.pointerType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PointerEvent/pointerType)

```js
window.oncontextmenu = function (event: any) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log(event); // prints [object PointerEvent]

  const pointerEvent = event as PointerEvent;
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log(`window.oncontextmenu: ${pointerEvent.pointerType}`);

  if (pointerEvent.pointerType === 'touch') {
    // context menu was triggerd by long press
    return false;
  }

  // just to show that pointerEvent.pointerType has another value 'mouse' aka right click
  if (pointerEvent.pointerType === 'mouse') {
    // context menu was triggered by right click
    return true;
  }

  // returning true will show a context menu for other cases
  return true;
};
```